# C++ : Opencv Camera control APIs Vs Android NDK Camera APIs

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I am using OpenCV on Android, i would like to user Camera control APIs for the same. I can see that Android [NDK is providing camera control APIs (level 24 and above)](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis#camera).

- With Android NDK, i can control the camera with much better control for android platform.
- With Android NDK, i need to convert the the image to OpenCV Mat object for further processing.

What i am not sure about is following:

How OpenCV controls Android camera till today, was it via Java APIs? Or were there specially written C++ APIs?

Also if you suggest what is the best approach to control Android cameras?

Comment: From my experience, OpenCV's camera control is very limited on Android. That is if it even works at all. You are better off implementing camera control via the NDK, mind you, you will have to write some non-trivial code to glue together C++ and Java. Another option is to use a mobile development framework like QT framework, which has C++ implemented classes that handle mobile resources like cameras with a lot of clear documentation that makes the integration a lot more... straightforward. Nevertheless, you will still have to write some interfaces between C++ and Java.